# What is the word for

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, learning

I am studying German and I'm looking for the "assembled" word
that sums up the complex concept of:

> looking intently in the eyes of a person and hope that she will say what he does not have the courage to say

E.g. this can describes the *shyness* of a lover, face to face his "opponent"...

Comment: Like *ermutigend*, *erwartungsvoll*, *neugierig*?

Comment: Don't know what you want to say with "assembled" (?)

Comment: I think that there is a notion nowadays worldwide that German language speakers come up with compound words for every thinkable concept that is thrown at them. It's not totally wrong... :-)

Comment: @HalvarF great Idea. lets make up some words for it: 
"Liebesbekundungshoffnungsblick" - usage: "Du kannst dir deinen Liebesbekundungshoffnungsblick sparen. Ich will es zuerst von dir hören!"

Answer (score 1):

It's "hoffnungsvoll herzheischender Hundeblick" (hopeful heart-seeking puppy dog eyes).

And yes, I completely made that up for you to use.

Comment: The meaning of *herzheischend* and *heart-appealing* in this context is not transparent to me. An online search did not help for lack of results (separate from a song). The only thing that comes to my mind is *herz**erweich**end*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Ist aber gut erfunden!

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: appealing might not be the best translation for heischend, I edited.

Comment: I voted up because I liked the invention, especially "herzheischend": it sounds great, and with "heischen" you revitalize a word that is almost gone. But looking it up, I saw that the meaning is different from what we need here. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heischen 
"Heischen" is authoritative, looking downward. 
So I rather suggest the upward gazing "herzflehend".

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to say in few words:
my favorite would be " eindringlich ansehen" or " tief in die Augen schauen"
another one: fragend beobachten, fragende Blicke werfen
the following are not exactly in the full meaning:
seinen Blick (an die Person) heften, jemand mit seinen Blicken verfolgen, suchend/intensiv betrachten,
seinen Blick nicht ablassen
dahinschmachten

Answer (score 0):

Mein Vorschlag: auffordernd-eindringlich tief in die Augen schauen. Not very "assembled", is it?